# Play/Pause/Rewind mp3 Audio on Web Page

Tags: mp3, flash

I've been looking for a while for a good web page embed-able mp3 player.  I've considered going with the Wimpy Player, but it appears to have problems with Flash 10, and their customer support is unresponsive.

My requirements are pretty simple, I want to be able to play/pause/rewind audio.  I'd also like to be able to embed the player multiple times on the same page as well as be able to play a playlist of multiple mp3s.

Any products other than Wimpy that I should be investigating?

Any advice is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [jPlayer](http://www.happyworm.com/jquery/jplayer/).

Comment: Very cool.  This is SOOOOO much better (and FREE).  Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 0):

Did you try the player from longtail? 
http://www.longtailvideo.com/players/jw-flv-player/

Work for me, and i belive is better as it dosent user HTML5, which is not fully supported across browsers.